# Which function should i use to convert an image to grayscale using GOIMAGICK in GO

Tags: go-imagick

I want to convert an image to grayscale using magickwand in GOIMAGICK, but which one should I use: `BlurImage(radius, sigma float64)` error or `BrightnessContrastImage(brightness, contrast float64)` error?

Answer (score 1):

With ImageMagick  MagickWand it goes like this:

```
  MagickQuantizeImage(image_wand,256,GRAYColorspace,0,MagickFalse,MagickFalse);
```

So, why not go for QuantizeImage?